# Double subscript error?

Tags: equations, subscripts

I want to type the below formula.

[image: my desired formula]

When I type I get an error saying Double subscript

The code I wrote for this formula

```
\left \{ e_{ij}^{l} \right \}_{i,j}_{\in \omega _{l}}
```

Comment: Is it i, j which are in ω_l?

Comment: yes i,j are in w_l

Comment: I guess you want `_{i,j\in\omega_{l}}`

Comment: Incidentally, consider using `\ell` instead of `l`

Answer (score 6):

It must be either

```
\left \{ e_{ij}^{l} \right \}_{i,j_{\in \omega_{l}}}
```

[image: double subscript]

for a real double (in fact a triple) subscript or

```
\left \{ e_{ij}^{l} \right \}_{i,j \in \omega _{l}}
```

[image: single subscript]

if everything should be in a single subscript line, which is what you want to achieve, I guess ...

Comment: I don't think it's necessary (let alone that it's a good idea) to keep using the OP's `\left` and `\right` directives in order to get the `{i,j \in \omega _{l}}` subscript to be placed quite low. It should suffice to encase `\{e_{ij}^{l}\}` in an extra pair of curly braces, i.e., to write `{\{e_{ij}^{l}\}}`. For sure, this solution would avoid enlarging the curly braces.

Comment: @Mico: You’re right … I just took the original code and fixed the subscript problem …

Answer (score 5):

The code that comes closest to replicating the screenshot you posted is

```
${{\{e_{ij}^{l}\}}_{i,j}}{}_{\in\omega_l}$
```

[image]

However, this somehow doesn't look quite right. I suspect that either

```
${{\{e_{ij}^{l}\}}_{i,j\in\omega_l}}$
```

or

```
${{\{e_{ij}^{l}\}}_{i,j}}\in\omega_l$
```

is what's actually needed.

[image]

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
${{\{e_{ij}^{l}\}}_{i,j}}{}_{\in\omega_l}$
\quad
${{\{e_{ij}^{l}\}}_{i,j\in\omega_l}}$
\quad
${{\{e_{ij}^{l}\}}_{i,j}}\in\omega_l$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Vote positively your beautiful answer. Now even if I do not read who is the user who provided the answer I immediately understand the way you write that you are.

Comment: @Sebastiano - Dear friend, many thanks for the beautiful compliment!! I very much appreciate it!!

Comment: You are very good. Why should I never write or deny it?

Comment: @Sebastiano - Still more thanks! :-) It's really really nice to get this sort of direct feedback that one's efforts at providing solutions are appreciated.